# Windows 10 - script with regex to compare partial filenames and copy over ones that don't exist

Tags: windows, batch, filenames, copy

I'm running Windows 10.

I'd like to copy many files from a folder into another, and probably I need a script, or any else solution that can do it.

I have 2 folders:
the folder `A` contains files named like this:

```
00010_name0_1680x1050.jpg
00020_name11_1680x1050.jpg
00021_name222_1680x1050.jpg
00022_name300_1680x1050.jpg
```

while the destination folder `B` has files named like this:

```
00010_name0_1920x1200.jpg
00020_name11_1920x1200.jpg
00021_name222_1920x1200.jpg
00030_name500_1920x1200.jpg
```

So filenames are the same except they differ in the last part, about the resolution.

I'd like to copy all the files from `A` to `B`, but only those that have a different first part of the name, until last `_` which separates resolution.

So maybe I need a regex script that could compare names and decide if to copy them or not. Any kind of simple solution will be appreciated.

Comment: Interpreting his/her question, I estimate that he/she wants to merge the low resolution files with the high resolution files, preferring the high resolution files (of course). So the name is the first part and the resolution the appendix.

Comment: Ah, I was thinking similarly, but wasn't sure, thanks for clearing it up. So now the only question is - what did you try? Any kind of attempt is expected to be seen in questions here normally, especially for very specific requests that won't help too many other people.

Comment: Yes, it's correct: I'd like to merge the low resolution files with the high resolution files, preferring the high resolution files.

I did not tried any kind of attempt yet. I have no idea where to start from.

Comment: Ok, I'll help you later today because I'm in a good mood, but keep in mind for next time you need to include any sort attempt next time. PowerShell is not hard to learn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this kind of PowerShell script:

```
# Save directory paths to vars
$dirA = C:\Some\Folder\A
$dirB = C:\Some\Folder\B

# Get file names of each found .jpg (with 1920x1200 in name)
$fileNamesB = (Get-ChildItem -Path $dirB -Filter *_1920x1200.jpg).Name

# Get prefixes of names that shouldn't be copied, by removing the resolution postfix
# % is shorthand for ForEach-Object 
$prefixesB = $fileNamesB | % { $_ -replace "_1920x1200\.jpg$", '' }

$filesA = Get-ChildItem -Path $dirA -Filter *_1680x1050.jpg
# Filter files by checking their name property against our prefixes
# ? is shorthand for Where-Object
$filteredFilesA = $filesA | ? { ($_.Name -replace "_1680x1050\.jpg$", '') -NotIn $prefixesB } 

# Copy the filtered files to folder B
$filteredFilesA | Copy-Item -Destination $dirB
```

Explantation of functions are in the comments.

Comment: Thanks! That script worked fine, 249 files have been copied.